# Any ways to get first date created of video files?

Tags: c#

When you copy a video file from your smart phone to your desktop the value of "Date Created" property of the video file is modified to current date.

I need to get the original creation date of the file. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe there´s some `EXIF` information within the file...

Comment: You may want to show us the code you are using for copying the video file.

Answer (score 0):

As your question tagged for C#, I believe you want to do it with C#.

You can use [CreationTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of FileInfo instance.

```
var info = new FileInfo(filename_with_full_path);
DateTime creationTime = info.CreationTime;
```

Comment: Like I was saying the CreationTime gives the date the file is copied to another device (computer) not the Date recorded or first date created.